# Invalid expression in XPATH

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrape from Google Search the first links using Selenium.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy import Selector

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

start_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=Iwtglobal+linkedin"

def parse(link):
    driver.get(link)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    selector = Selector(text=page_source)
    link = selector.xpath('//div(contains[@class="MjjYud"])').extract()
    print(link)
```

```py
File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1599, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //div(contains[@class="MjjYud"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], not a minimal-minimal-reproducable-example.  Where/How is `driver` and `Selector` defined?

Comment: add this, the problem is with XPATH expression

Comment: Can you try: `"//div[contains(@class='MjjYud')]"`  (Try, because `pip install lxml` is returning an error here )

Comment: the same problem as with "//div[contains(@class='MjjYud')]", somehow the same syntax works on different sites (with different programs)
For example this code: https://github.com/AndreyPushkinA/VS-Code/blob/master/Indeed/indeed_selenium.py

Comment: solve the problem, "//div[contains(@class, 'MjjYud')]" works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

> link = selector.xpath(//div[contains(@class, 'MjjYud')]).extract()

here div is the selector not a function. Where contains is a function which take two arguments, one is element attribute another is attribute value. You assigned class attribute to a value like @class = foo. which is not correct.